# Handling variables/commands with spaces throughout a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm currently working with a large code base, and I want to move some of my bash scripts to run their python commands via a python docker container. To achieve this, I've created a function "python" and placed this in a script which can be sourced into the scripts I want to run via containers

```
function python() {
    python_command_to_run="${@}"
    docker run --rm --name py-container -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app my_image:latest python ${python_command_to_run}
}
```

However, python commands I have which contain spaces will not work. An example of said command is the following

```
python "my_py_script.py" --run_command '"echo hi"'
```

I believe that when passed into the docker run, the code believes `"echo` is one command and `hi"` is another. This is because I'm getting an argument exception in my actual python script

How do I modify the above "python" function or my call of said function such that it treats the "echo hi" as a single command to my python script?

Comment: Use an array: `python_command_to_run=( "$@" )` and then use the expansion `"${python_command_to_run[@]}"` (with double quotes and `[@]`).

Comment: Do you have to assign `"$@"` to a variable? It should work fine on its own

Comment: @oguz ismail Yes I wanted it in a variable if at all possible. The above answer from gniouf worked